# Google Maps in IE7 - external absolute positioned elements falling behind

Tags: css, google-maps, css-position

I have a Google Map embedded on my page and a drop down menu falling behind it in IE7.

This is happening because IE7 doesn't know how to position the z-index values for elements properly if there is an element positioned relative thrown into the mix.

In the past when I've run into this problem there is usually an element positioned relatively that wasn't necessary. A quick - position:static and all is fine.

But in this case Google Maps needs the map_canvas to be positioned relatively so that the pieces of map can be positioned...

Is there another work around out there? Any other solutions that anyone can suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the html and CSS code. Maybe a fiddle or a live example. I am sure i had a similar problem and fixed it buit can't seem to recall. If the above is provided, maybe it will come to me.

Comment: Wish I could, it's on a closed server. Thanks, was hoping maybe someone might have had some experience with it and recall a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No access to IE7 here, so I am not sure this works... but you could try the following: keep the Google Maps `div` as `position:relative;` but try placing it inside another `div` that is `position:absolute;`

Answer (score -1):

Give the dropdowns parent element a higher z-index as well.

Comment: Nope, as I mentioned in the question, in IE7 that doesn't have any effect because the map_canvas is positioned relative.